# WPF Geometry.Parse method for Direct2D

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, geometry, directx

Is there any equivalent of the [Geometry.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method that is used to parse a string that follows the [Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293(v=vs.110).aspx)?

If there is not a such equivalent method how should I implement it by means of `Visual C++` and `Direct2D`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately no. I had to implement my own version.